# IOS 5.0.1 With XCode 4.2.1 Saying "does not match any of the versions of iOS"

Tags: ios5, xcode4.2

I am currently on Xcode 4.2.1 and I am running an IPad 1 using 5.0.1.  However, I am getting this error message:

> The version of iOS on “Personal iPad” does not match any of the
>   versions of iOS supported for development with this installation of
>   the iOS SDK. Please restore the device to a version of the OS listed
>   below, or update to the latest version of the iOS SDK; which is
>   available here.
>
> OS Installed on Personal iPad
>   5.0.1 (9A405)
>
> Xcode Supported iOS Versions

That's right!  It is giving me absolutely no supported iOS versions.  I have seen other posts about this for older versions of Xcode/IOS, but they also had supported versions.

Edit: I can run the program just fine in the iOS device simulator.  It runs in IOS 5.  Also, my provisioning profiles are listed under the device and they have matched my certificate in the KeyChain.

Comment: is there a "use for development" button for your device in your Xcode organizer?

Comment: I am experiencing the same...

Comment: When I get home today. I am going to try to uninstall/reinstall XCode.  It isn't the most elegant method, but if it works I will let you guys know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok!  I downloaded the installer program for XCode.  Uninstalled XCode and reinstalled it through the installer program and it works like a charm.

So, I ran this to uninstall it:

```
sudo /Developer/Library/uninstall-devtools –mode=all
```

Then I just used the installer from the App Store and now it works just fine with my iPad.

Thanks.

Comment: I uninstalled and reinstalled but still couldn't find the image for 5.0.1 for my iPhone 4S.  If I click about, the xcode version is correct (4.2.1) but the iPhone SDK is 5.0 instead of 5.0.1.  Help please!

Comment: This worked for me. I didn't have to uninstall, just re-downloaded the installer and let it install over the old version.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't need to uninstall xcode.
just start the installer and press "update"...

Answer (score 0):

For those who wan't to avoid upgrading Xcode, do the following:

1. Download the Xcode version dmg containing the iOS SDK you need
2. Make sure Xcode is not running
3. Double click the downloaded Xcode dmg, right click the Xcode.app icon, choose "Show Package Content"
4. Copy Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/ to /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs (on you local machine)
5. Copy Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/ to /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer (on you local machine)
6. Copy Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/ to /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport (on you local machine)
7. Right click Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/, choose "Make Alias", rename the alias to "Latest"
8. Start Xcode